# How to filter data from a data frame when the number of columns are dynamic?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below

```
    A_Name  B_Detail  Value_B  Value_C   Value_D ......
0   AA      X1        1.2      0.5       -1.3    ......
1   BB      Y1        0.76     -0.7      0.8     ......
2   CC      Z1        0.7      -1.3      2.5     ......
3   DD      L1        0.9      -0.5      0.4     ......
4   EE      M1        1.3      1.8       -1.3    ......
5   FF      N1        0.7      -0.8      0.9     ......
6   GG      K1        -2.4     -1.9      2.1     ......
```

This is just a sample of data frame, I can have n number of columns like (Value_A, Value_B, Value_C, ........... Value_N)

Now i want to filter all rows where absolute value of all columns (Value_A, Value_B, Value_C, ....) is less than 1.

If you have limited number of columns, you can filter the data by simply putting 'and' condition on columns in dataframe, but I am not able to figure out what to do in this case.

I don't know what would be number of such columns, the only thing I know that such columns would be prefixed with 'Value'.

In above case output should be like

```
    A_Name  B_Detail  Value_B  Value_C   Value_D ......
1   BB      Y1        0.76     -0.7      0.8     ......
3   DD      L1        0.9      -0.5      0.4     ......
5   FF      N1        0.7      -0.8      0.9     ......
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for creating `mask` and then [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.filter(like='Value').abs() < 1).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
  A_Name B_Detail  Value_B  Value_C  Value_D
1     BB       Y1     0.76     -0.7      0.8
3     DD       L1     0.90     -0.5      0.4
5     FF       N1     0.70     -0.8      0.9
```

All combination in **timings**:

```
#len df = 70k, 5 columns
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [47]: %timeit (df[(df.filter(like='Value').abs() < 1).all(axis=1)])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.48 ms per loop

In [48]: %timeit (df[df.filter(regex=r'Value').abs().lt(1).all(1)])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.02 ms per loop

In [49]: %timeit (df[df.filter(like='Value').abs().lt(1).all(1)])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.02 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit (df[(df.filter(regex=r'Value').abs() < 1).all(axis=1)])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.3 ms per loop
```

---

```
#len df = 70k, 5k columns
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, axis=1)
#only for testing, create unique columns names
df.columns = df.columns.str[:-1] + [str(col) for col in list(range(df.shape[1]))]
print (df)

In [75]: %timeit ((df[(df.filter(like='Value').abs() < 1).all(axis=1)]))
1 loop, best of 3: 10.3 s per loop

In [76]: %timeit ((df[(df.filter(regex=r'Value').abs() < 1).all(axis=1)]))
1 loop, best of 3: 10.3 s per loop

In [77]: %timeit (df[df.filter(regex=r'Value').abs().lt(1).all(1)])
1 loop, best of 3: 10.4 s per loop

In [78]: %timeit (df[df.filter(like='Value').abs().lt(1).all(1)])
1 loop, best of 3: 10.1 s per loop
```

Comment: :-) virtually the same

Comment: for some reason there is a subtle difference in timing.  Test it on your end.

Comment: Two differences are `like` vs `regex` and `lt` vs `<`

Comment: `like` is faster than `regex` but `lt` is faster than `<` by a larger margin.  adding timing.

Answer (score 4):

- Use `filter` to get the columns you care about.
- `abs().lt(1)` to get find cells less than 1.
- `all(1)` to find rows where all `Value`'s are less than 1.

---

```
df[df.filter(regex=r'Value').abs().lt(1).all(1)]
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

**conclusion**

`like` is faster than `regex`
`lt` is faster than `<`

fastest solution is combining best of both:

```
df[df.filter(like='Value').abs().lt(1).all(1)]
```

[image]

**breakdown**

[image]

Comment: You are right with colclusion, i add timing in large dataframe with 5000 columns ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to filter on the column name (even if they're prefixed), you can also use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) :

```
>>> df[df.ix[:,2:].abs().lt(1).all(1)]
      A_Name B_Detail  Value_B  Value_C  Value_D
1     BB       Y1     0.76     -0.7      0.8
3     DD       L1     0.90     -0.5      0.4
5     FF       N1     0.70     -0.8      0.9
```

This supposes all your "value" columns are after your "detail" columns.

And since everyone's benchmarking, this is even faster :

```
In [7]: %timeit df[df.ix[:,2:].abs().lt(1).all(1)]                                                              
1000 loops, best of 3: 803 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit df[df.filter(like='Value').abs().lt(1).all(1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 939 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the columns using [str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) then use [apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `lambda` :

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Value')]
df[df[cols].apply(lambda x: abs(x) < 1).sum(axis=1) == len(cols)]
```

Output:

```
        A_Name  B_Detail    Value_B     Value_C     Value_D
1       BB      Y1          0.76        -0.7        0.8
3       DD      L1          0.90        -0.5        0.4
5       FF      N1          0.70        -0.8        0.9
```